# error: expecting member declaration and error: unresolved reference: in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In class Parent.

```
interface Humenable{
    fun Run()
}
```

In class Child.

```
fun main(args:Array<String>)
{   


    class Student : Humenable{
    Overrides fun Run(){

            println("Pass")
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Change `Overrides fun Run(){` to `override fun Run() {`. That's your typo. And move `Student` class declaration outside of `fun main`'s scope.

Comment: Thank you :)  @PeterSamokhin

Comment: Now I get  "error: modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'top level function'
override fun Run(){"
^

Comment: Check my answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
interface Humenable {
    fun Run()
}

class Student : Humenable {
    override fun Run() {
        println("Pass")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val student = Student()
    student.Run()
}
```

Your mistakes:

- You used `Overrides` instead `override` modifier (simple typo).
- You made `Student` class declaration in `fun {}` scope.